# Dúvidas sobre o método toString() da classe Object

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Eu estive fazendo alguns testes com o método `toString()` da classe `java.lang.Object` e descobri que o resultado obtido muda a cada execução, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

#### Trecho do código testado

```
public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NovaClasse NC = new NovaClasse();
        System.out.println(NC.toString());
    } 
}
```

**Saídas obtidas**

```
NovaClasse@1f1fba0
NovaClasse@1befab0
NovaClasse@13c5982
```

Descobri que o método `toString()` retorna o nome da classe ao qual o objeto pertence + @ + 7 caracteres hexadecimais que primeiramente pensei que fossem referentes ao endereço da memória em que o objeto foi armazenado, más parece que eles são um `hashCode`.

#### Dúvidas

O que é e qual a utilidade desse `hashCode`? Por que o seu valor varia de uma execução para a outra se o meu código continua o mesmo?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

De acordo com a própria [documentação da classe Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), o método `toString()` retorna uma representação em String do objeto.

Olhando no código, a implementação do método `toString()` vemos:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

O que não deixa de ser uma representação do objeto, porém, é uma representação que não nos serve de muita coisa, pois a informação retornada não tem valor para nós usuários.

O método `toString()` passa a ter valor quando sobrescrevemos ele fazendo ele retornar o que consideramos relevante para o objeto.

Exemplo:

```
class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome;}
    public int getIdade() { return idade; }
    public void setIdade(int idade) { this.idade = idade; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Me chamo: " + this.getNome() + ", tenho: " + this.getIdade() + " anos.";
    }
}

public class TestePessoa {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("Bob", 20);
        System.out.println(pessoa);
    }
}
```

Retorna:

> Me chamo: Bob, tenho: 20 anos.

Ou seja, sobrescrevemos o método `toString()` para que as informações mostradas pelo objeto sejam interessantes para nós em um exemplo didático, ao invés de uma representação em hexadecimal do `hashCode()` do objeto, que não usamos para nada.

**EDIT**

O método `println()` é sobrecarregado para imprimir inúmeros tipos diferentes de dados, no seu exemplo você usou o método `println(String)`:

```
System.out.println(NC.toString());
```

Você fez uma chamada explícita ao método `toString()` do seu objeto, já no meu exemplo eu chamei o método `toString()` implicitamente, usando a versão sobrecarregada `println(Object)`, que por definição retorna uma representação em String do objeto, ou seja, ele imprime o retorno do método `toString()` do seu objeto.

**EDIT2**

> O que é e qual a utilidade desse hashCode? Por que o seu valor varia de uma execução para a outra se o meu código continua o mesmo?

A implementação do `hashCode()` na classe Object não importa muito para nós, [de acordo com a própria documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.

Em tradução livre:

> É tipicamente implementado convertendo o endereço interno de um objeto em um inteiro, mas essa técnica de implementação não é necessária pela linguagem de programação JavaTM.

O `hashCode()` também é um método que deve ser sobrescrito se desejamos usar com consistência. Ele costuma ser usado para encontrar objetos dentro de uma [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), mas acho que sua discussão foge do escopo da pergunta, então encerro por aqui.

Answer (score 11):

Eu vou discordar da resposta do Math. Ela não está errada, mas ele mesmo fornece um *link* para a documentação que diz como o método deve ser escrito, e a resposta, na minha avaliação, não faz o que a documentação diz. Eu sei que há quem pense como ele, mas eu acho que aprenderam com alguém que não entendeu a documentação e continuam fazendo errado.

Vamos pegar a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

Tem mais:

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

Aí diz que deve usar o nome da classe neste método. Claro que dar algum valor de identidade é mais útil que só o nome da classe, terá vantagens. Mas essa é a implementação padrão.

Pensa, se um dia precisar retornar um texto diferente, o que fará? Trocar esse texto? E se a aplicação depende daquele texto específico para fazer algo? Afinal o método é de mecanismo, ele pode ser usado para qualquer coisa que envolva a representação e ela deve ser estável, o resultado faz parte do contrato da API. E se precisar mudar mesmo, teria que criar um outro método, viraria uma bagunça, só porque está misturando funções.

Há alguma controvérsia sobre o uso conceitual certo.

O meu entendimento e de muitas [pessoas muito mais experientes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42396672/221800) e com formação (no sentido amplo, não de estudo certificado apenas) muito melhor que eu, é que esse método tem função de depuração ou no máximo pra conversão de dados para serialização ou alguma atividade bem específica que tem mais a ver com o mecanismo do que com a regra de negócio.

Há quem discorde disso, e em Java parece haver a cultura de ser mais que isso, o que demonstra uma cultura esquisita porque é uma linguagem que tenta fazer o que é mais correto, mesmo que nem sempre seja prático, mas nesse ponto, em exceções e outras coisas, procuram o mais prático mesmo que conceitualmente esteja errado.

O método deveria apenas retornar a identidade simples do objeto. Alguma coisa que indique que objeto é esse, qual o seu conteúdo importante de forma mais básica possível. Se não der para retornar algo assim, retorne o nome da classe, caso de *array*.

Se quer uma mensagem formatada, crie um método para retornar assim. Se quer padronizado, até pode usar um `toString(alguma coisa)` ([assinatura diferente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101)), assim com uma assinatura diferente do que está em todo objeto já é algo que não é feito para atender as necessidade do mecanismo.

Se enfeitar o texto do `toString()` fosse o certo o `Integer` deveria ser assim:

```
public String toString() {
     return String.format("O valor do objeto é %s", String.valueOf(value);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/ToString.java).

É isto que está fazendo na classe da resposta do Math. Isto é muito errado. Não é culpa dele, todo mundo faz assim, então todo mundo acha que eu estou errado. É uma questão de interpretar a documentação.

Isto é representativo do objeto? É conciso? Eu acho que não. O Java até incentiva o certo, mas muita gente não interpreta a documentação.

Eu gostaria que Java tivesse algo padrão um pouco melhor para resultar em texto com firulas, pelo menos eu desconheço algo. C# fez isto. Por isso que as pessoas reclamam desses pequenos problemas do Java. Toda tecnologia que vem depois de uma que faz sucesso tende a evitar certos erros do seu antecessor.

Mas eu concordo que o foco da pergunta, sobre o *hashcode*, foi bem respondido pelo Math, por isso tem meu voto nela.

Comment: De fato nunca tinha me atentado para qual o real significado do "informação útil" que deve ser retornado pelo toString(), no meu caso usei um exemplo mais didático apesar de poder induzir ao erro na hora de implementar em uma situação real. Gostei da sua resposta no que diz do uso conceitual correto tem mais a ver com o mecanismo, como por exemplo uma serialização, +1