# Como trocar o modo da qual uma classe/estrutura é impressa?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, struct, polimorfismo

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
struct cores
{
    int r, g, b;

    public cores(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Caso eu mande imprimir uma nova estrutura, ficaria assim:

```
Console.WriteLine(new cores(1, 0, 0));
//Saída Program.cores
```

Mas eu gostaria que a saída fosse:

```
Console.WriteLine(new cores(1, 0, 0));
//Saída R: 1 - G: 0 - B: 0
```

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Sei que já existem algumas perguntas parecidas aqui no SO, mas nenhuma especifica ao caso descrito, e quando eu fui procurar por aqui, foi bem difícil encontrar, alem do conteúdo não estar em bom estado para aprendizado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Algumas considerações fariam esta estrutura ser melhor:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => WriteLine(new Cores(80, 20, 160));
}

struct Cores {
    public byte R { get; }
    public byte G { get; }
    public byte B { get; }
    
    public Cores(byte r, byte g, byte b) {
        R = r;
        G = g;
        B = b;
    }
    public override string ToString() => $"{R}, {G}, {B}";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/97U3rX). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/twev1G). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Struct/ToString.cs).

- [Tipos devem usam padrão CamelCase](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32665/101).
- Propriedades também.
- [Estruturas quase sempre devem ser imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), especialmente esta, então os membros não podem ser modificados externamente.
- Membros que devem ser expostos a toda aplicação devem ser declarados como `public` para funcionar sempre e não apenas por coincidência.
- [`ToString()` não é um método de apresentação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212797/101), é de [depuração, de conversão simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212758/101), ele deve ser facilmente *parseáveis*, o que eu nem sei se eu já não exagerei.
- Para um RGB o tipo subjacente é o `byte` e não o `int`, uma economia de 9 bytes, ou 75%.
- O resto é estilístico apenas.
- Tem outras melhorias para ser um tipo "decente", mas não vem ao caso aqui.

Comment: Não fale assim do meu tipo. ;-;

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer isso você pode dar um [override](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override) no método [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) em sua estrutura:

```
struct cores
{
    int r, g, b;

    public cores(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return $"R: {r} - G: {g} - B: {b}";
    }
}
```

E escrever normalmente:

```
Console.WriteLine(new cores(1, 0, 0));
//Saída R: 1 - G: 0 - B: 0
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/vdCh0H).