# Por que está retornando o caminho da classe

Tags: java

Estou fazendo uma simples agenda e quando eu vou imprimir os valores mostra o caminho da classe.

Por que isso está acontecendo?

A mensagem que o console mostra

> [br.novo.itdd.Person@15db9742, br.novo.itdd.Person@6d06d69c]

Minha classe Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Schedule schedule = new Schedule();

    schedule.addContact("claro", "1052");
    schedule.addContact("oi", "10331");
    System.out.println(schedule.getPerson());
}
```

Classe `Schedule`

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Schedule {

    private List<Person> person;

    public Schedule() {
        this.person = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }

    public void showSchedule(){
        System.out.println(this.getPerson());
    }

    public List<Person> getPerson() {
        return person;
    }   

    public boolean addContact(String name, String number){

        this.person.add(new Person(name, number));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Classe `Person`

```
public class Person {           
    private String name, cellNumber;

    public Person(String name, String cellNumber) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setCellNumber(cellNumber);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if(name.length() >= 2) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public String getCellNumber() {
        return cellNumber;
    }

    public void setCellNumber(String cellNumber) {
        if (cellNumber.length() >= 4) {
            this.cellNumber = cellNumber;
        }
    }

    public boolean validateDate() {

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É porque esta é a implementação padrão do método `toString()`. Você pode ver mais sobre isso na publicação: [Dúvidas sobre o método toString() da classe Object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10893/18246)

Você pode especificar o que quer imprimir na chamada do método `println` ou então sobrescrever o `toString()`.

Especificando no `println`

```java
Person person = schedule.getPerson();
System.out.println(
  String.format("Name: %s, Cellphone: %s", person.getName(), person.getCellNumber()));
```

Reescrevendo o `toString()`

```java
public class Person {
    // ...
    @Override
    public string toString() {
        return String.format("Name: %s, Cellphone: %s", getName(), getCellNumber());
    }   
}
```

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo

Comment: @Thor De nada. Só pra constar: Sempre que você fizer uma pergunta e ela for respondida, você pode marcar a resposta que te atendeu melhor como correta usando o **✓** do lado esquerdo dela.